# Javascript: call function from function while maintaining both arguments

Tags: javascript, function, call

```
function a(x) {
    //...
    return { b: b(arguments) }
}

function b(x, args) {
    // x = foo
    // args[0] = bar
}

a("foo").b("bar");
​
```

How do I get this to work ?
Inside function `b` I want to access `x` from function `a` and `x` from function `b` after this call: `a("foo").b("bar");`

Comment: For you to even have a chance for this to work, `b()` needs to be a method on whatever `a()` returns and you can then put `x` as a property on that same return value.  I've put an example of this in my  answer.

Comment: @elias94xx, I think It's time for you to say what can and can't be modified in that code of yours. All those answers seems to believe you can freely the functions, is that correct?

Comment: @Alexander Actually both answers work for me. I'd go with the prototype based solution though, since my application uses them too.

Comment: @elias94xx, those assumptions were right ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `b(arguments)` will be called immediately, `b(arguments)` have to return a reference to a function for that to work. Something like this:

```
function a(x) {
    //...
    return { b: b(arguments) }
}

function b(x, args) {
    return function () {
       alert(x[0]); // Will alert foo
    };
}

a("foo").b("bar");​
```

Like this `b(arguments)` will be called immediately, and the return will be a reference to a function. When you then call `.b("bar")`, the returned function reference will be called. That function is within the scope of function b, since it is declared within it,  and therefor the arguments passed to `a` will be available.

A working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XcgwV/

Comment: Thanks, I'd accept this answer too but the prototype based solution is a bit more handy in my situation.

Comment: @elias94xx jfriend00's solution is better indeed. My answer just presents the minimum thing you would need to do in order to get your example-code to work, and how it works.

Comment: I actually ended up using your solution now. I didn't quite get it at first and wanted to quickly pick an answer. There is this benefit of not having to set an extra variable in the main object when using prototypes.

Comment: @elias94xx Glad you found it useful, even though my explanation might not have been the most clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you make `a()` and `b()` methods of the same object and `a()` stores it's argument in that object, you can get access to it from `b()`.

```
function foo() {};
foo.prototype = {
    a: function(x) {
        // do whatever you want
        this.arg = x;
        return(this);
    },
    b: function(y) {
        // y is what is passed here
        // this.arg is what was passed to a
    }
};

var obj = new foo();
obj.a("foo").b("bar");
​
```

Comment: Heh! I had no idea you could create a constructor with 'function x()', rather than 'function x(){}'. That's pretty useful if you plan to do nothing with it.

Comment: @Charlie - that was just a typo which I fixed.

Comment: Indeed... I should have ran that on the console first... :P

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you:

```
function a(x) {
    return {
        b: function(y) {
            //here you can access both x and y
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, the function in my application is defined outside as a prototype.

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
function b(x, args) {
    document.writeln("fun b");
    // x = sup
    // args[0] = hi
}

function a(x) {
    document.writeln("fun a");
    return { b1: b }
}

a("foo").b1("bar");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about passing the result of a(x), straight into b() as an option? Like;

```
function a(x) {
    return x
}

function b(x, y) {
    var result = y ? x + y : x;
    return result;
}

b(x, a(x));
```

Calling 'a("foo").b("bar")' won't presently work as you've written it, as that currently implies that b() is a sub property of a{}. For me, I'd probably need to know a little more about what you're trying to do.